# Vue 2 Change search placeholder and search id on parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

So, I have this search component I created because I will use it several time.

My search Component (Child Component) looks like:

```
<template>
  <div class="input-group main-search">
    <input class="input-group-field" type="text" value="" :placeholder="placeholder" :id="searchId">
    <div class="input-group-button">
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: ['placeholder', 'searchId'],
  name: 'search',
  data() {
    return {
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

and I included it into my Parent component (Search pages with Categories)
the below example works for me... but I want to make it somehow possible to get data from returned data in this component and somehow to bind into.

```
<template>
  <search placeholder="placeholder text" id="id number"></search>
  <p>some text here </p>
</template>
```

So is there any form passing data from returned data like:

```
  data() {
    return {
      searchProps: [
        {
          placeholder: 'Watafaka',
          searchId: '2',
        },
      ],
```

Looking forward for help from someone :)

Comment: What exactly is your question? From where to where you want to pass data?

Comment: I have a child component, and I want to be able to change Child Components placeholder value from parent component

Comment: I think you answered your own question already?  You already have a prop called `placeholder` which the parent component can pass any value it wants to set the proper placeholder.

Comment: I am unclear by what you mean by "I want to make it somehow possible to get data from returned data in this component and somehow to bind into" - can you elaborate on that a bit more?  Do you mean you're trying to pass data from the child component (`<search>`) back up to the parent component (Search pages)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to pass the values by binding them. Check the below answer.

```
<template>
   <search :placeholder="placeholderValue" :searchId="searchId"></search>
   <p>some text here </p>
</template>

data() {
   return {
       placeholderValue: 'Watafaka',
       searchId: '2'
   }
}
```

Comment: thnx for your answer, but when I have a return than an array, it does not work, like in my example above in my question. I can not access it by searchProps.placeholder is there any way >??

Comment: yes, you can. pass it like this `:placeholder="searchProps[0].placeholder"`. You are using it as `searchProps.placeholder` which is wrong.